# Converting character to date with time zone using looping functions

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, strptime

**Given:**
A data frame with three character columns.

```
Date        Time    Zone
1950-04-18  01:30   CST
1950-04-18  01:45   CST
1951-02-20  16:00   CST
1951-06-08  09:00   CST
1951-11-15  15:00   CST
1951-11-15  20:00   CST
```

**Required:**
 1. Combine Date, Time and, Zone
 2. Convert from Character to Date

**What I have tried:**
1. `datetime <- paste(Date, Time)`
2. `strptime(datetime[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz=Zone[1])`

This successfully parses the first element, however, I would like to convert the entire data using one of the looping functions lapply or sapply.

How can I use loop functions to parse the entire vector?

**NOTE:** Forgot to mention earlier, the data contains various abbreviated time zones other than CST

Comment: How about using `lubridate` with `ymd_hm(paste(df$Date, df$Time))` and set timezone with `tz`

Comment: @Sotos `ymd_hm()` also requires the `tz` to be single character vector, is it possible to pick the value for `tz` from the **Zone** vector shown in the above example ?

Answer (score 3):

Timezones can be a tricky thing to handle as there are different formats being used. To get a list of the used timezones on your system, run `OlsonNames()` for the list.

The `CST` timezone you used in your example is not always supported and you might therefore get the following warning message when trying to use that as a timezone:

> In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CST'

I've constructed an example dataset (see below) to show how you can update your `datetime` with timezone information. The following `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(d))
  d$datetime[i] <- strftime(paste(d$Date, d$Time)[i],
                            format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", 
                            tz = as.character(d$Zone[i]),
                            usetz = TRUE)
```

will give:

```
> d
        Date  Time Zone             datetime
1 1950-04-18 01:30  GMT 1950-04-18 01:30 GMT
2 1950-04-18 01:45  CET 1950-04-18 01:45 CET
3 1951-02-20 16:00  EET 1951-02-20 16:00 EET
4 1951-06-08 09:00  EST 1951-06-08 09:00 EST
5 1951-11-15 15:00  WET 1951-11-15 15:00 WET
6 1951-11-15 20:00  MST 1951-11-15 20:00 MST
```

As said, your dataset might contain timezone abbreviations that are not recognized by your system. You could replace these with the help of [this list](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) for example.

---

Used data:

```
d <- read.table(text="Date        Time    Zone
1950-04-18  01:30   GMT
1950-04-18  01:45   CET
1951-02-20  16:00   EET
1951-06-08  09:00   EST
1951-11-15  15:00   WET
1951-11-15  20:00   MST", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I was thinking about trying to use a `for` loop in this case, but then I had to leave. Seems to be the right choice here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
df1<-data.frame(x = paste(df$Date,df$Time), Zone =df$Zone)
d<-mapply(FUN = strptime,x=df1$x,tz=as.character(df1$Zone),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",SIMPLIFY = F,USE.NAMES = F)
```

Comment: @RHertel made changes to the code but this solution works only if there is one value of "tz" which is not the case as per the latest edit.

Comment: Okay. This solution is working fine for me and I have checked it twice.

Comment: You are right, it does not throw an error. Sorry, I made a mistake while testing your answer: My original dataframe was called `df1` while yours is `df`, and you are using `df1`, too, but in a different context.

Comment: @RHertel Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you check the output? It gives me a long list of values and not a new dataframe column with datetime values .... (cc @RHertel)

Comment: I agree, @Jaap The output does not seem to correspond to the OP's desired output, and I'm not even sure it is complete. But I didn't want to insists on it and preferred to leave the decision to the OP. The previous version threw an error; the edited version doesn't.

Comment: @Jaap He specifically mentioned the use of apply family of functions, so I tried that and this was the closest I could get. I agree the output is not what he desired.

Comment: there might be a way though to converst that `mapply` output to the desired format (but I don't know how unfortunately)

Comment: @Jaap Please review now.